# Java Relational Algebra Union

Tags: java

I'm trying to take the String contents from 2 text files and perform a union with the tables.

However my code keeps outputting the table@hexidecimal object location, rather than the string content inside the file.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
/**
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Purpose : This class is used to create a row for a two dimensional data
 *
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
class Table {

    String ID = "";
    String name = "";

    Table(String ID, String name) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

/**
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Purpose : This class is used to show how to work with two dimensional data
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
public class RelationalAlgebra {

    /**
     * It reads a two columns table into a two dimensional array
     *
     * @return ArrayList<Table>
     * @throws IOException
     */
    ArrayList<Table> getTable(String fileName) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Table> T1 = new ArrayList<Table>();          // creates an array list

        File inFile = new File(fileName);                      // creates a file object 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);                 // Scanner is a reader class

        int repetition = 1;                // used to skip the 1st line from     input file
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {                     // reads until not data
            if (repetition == 1) {                      // if 1st line, skips
                scanner.next();
                scanner.next();
                repetition = 2;
            } else {                                    // else reads each column
                String ID = scanner.next();
                String name = scanner.next();
                T1.add(new Table(ID, name));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();                          // close input stream
        return T1;                                 // returns the new table in the form of ArrayList
    }

    /**
     * It prints the content of an ArrayList<Table>
     *
     * @param t
     */
    void printTable(ArrayList<Table> t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(t.get(i).ID + "\t" + t.get(i).name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * An entry point for program execution
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RelationalAlgebra rel = new RelationalAlgebra();       // creates an object of this class
        ArrayList<Table> T1 = new ArrayList<Table>();          // creates an instance of ArrayList
        ArrayList<Table> T2 = new ArrayList<Table>();

        T1 = rel.getTable("C:/Users/workspace/RelationalAlgebra/src/T1.txt");

        T2 = rel.getTable("C:/Users/workspace/RelationalAlgebra/src/T2.txt");

        rel.printTable(T1);
        rel.printTable(T2);// prints the newly created table


        //Performs Union without duplicates     
        Set<Table> tableUnion = new LinkedHashSet<Table>();
        tableUnion.addAll(T1);
        tableUnion.addAll(T2);
        tableUnion.toString();

        System.out.println("Union : " + tableUnion);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
//T1
1   A
26  Z
3   C

//T2
1   A
2   B
3   C

//From Set<Table> tableUnion
Union list: [Table@55f96302, Table@3d4eac69, Table@42a57993, Table@75b84c92, Table@6bc7c054, Table@232204a1]
```

Comment: Where's the 'merged' variable declared?

Comment: If you put `Table` objects into your `Set` and you get `Table@213423` when printing it, you need to implement the `toString()` method in `Table` and define there how the table's content is supposed to be transformed into one String

Comment: Sorry the Merged was removed, I just updated it.  Thank you for your input, Gamedroids, I was thinking the same about the toString but applied it to my last System.out.println statement.  Where should I put the toString in the table class?

Comment: I'm new to Java and taking it at a University. So any newb level advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you put simple `Strings` into a `Set`, Java knows what to do and how to print the set. Classes where it is less evident how their content should be printed, need to implement the `toString()` method. In your case something like that:

```
class Table {

    String ID = "";
    String name = "";

    Table(String ID, String name) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ID+" - "+ name;      // you can give the string any form you want and you can print anything you want. All that is required is that you return a String in that method.
    }
}
```

On another note: even if ID is usual for databases – in Java a variable should always start with a small letter. Only class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and added knowledge of java, GameDroids. I will give this a try and get back with you.

Comment: Hey can you help me with intersection, difference, and join?